# Combining Data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have two tables as follows
TableA  as

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     2     3    4
101   201   301  401
```

AND another table- tableB

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     2     3    4
```

Result tableC  or result should be

Result

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8

1     2    3    4    1    2    3     4
101   201  301  401  null null null  null
```

Basically want to save the common rows in the table wherever available.
I am using MYSQL

Comment: Looks like common LEFT JOIN by all 4 columns. The matching criteria must be formulated explicitly.

Comment: This looks like poor schema design, but it's too abstract at present to be certain

Comment: Follow the pivot-table tag.

Comment: For MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from TableA a left join TableB b
on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 = b.col3 and a.col4 = b.col4
```